# Cut first part of a string which contains a '/' in bash

Tags: git, bash

In a bash script I want to cut a branch name.
The branch name is always like: `origin/X.X.X-name`
I want to cut the `origin/` part so I can use `X.X.X-name`.

This is what I tried:

```
TEST=origin/1.1.1-name

echo "${TEST//origin/}";
```

The output is `/1.1.1-name`
How can I get rid of the `/` in the beginning using the same approach as I'm doing now. I do not prefer to start cutting etc.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use parameter expansion in `bash`

```
test=origin/1.1.1-name

printf "%s\n" "${test##*/}"
1.1.1-name
```

From this [Parameter-expansion documentation](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) under sub-string removal.

> `${PARAMETER##PATTERN}`
>
> This form is to remove the described pattern trying to match it from the beginning of the string. The operator `#` will try to remove the shortest text matching the pattern, while `##` tries to do it with the longest text matching.

You also could use the regex operator `bash` provides (relatively newer versions of `bash`) to match the string.

```
[[ $test =~ /(.*)$ ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

---

You could of course third-party shell utils for this also, e.g using `cut`

```
cut -d/ -f2 <<<"$test"
```

meaning using de-limiter `/` cut the second field (`-f2`).